# Error al retornar JSON: "Unexpected token in JSON at position 0"

Tags: php, javascript, json

Ejecuto la consulta SQL y recibo el array procesado con *`fetch_assoc`*. Finalmente en `php` lo devuelvo a través de ajax con *`json_encode`*.

```
echo json_encode($this->rows);
```

Y este sería el código en JS:

```
function search(){ //recojo los datos y llamo a askDatabase
    var id_vehicle = document.buscar.id_vehicle.value;
    var brand = document.buscar.brand.value;

    askDatabase(id_vehicle, brand);
}

function askDatabase(id_vehicle, brand){ //Comunicación con PHP

    __ajax("controller.php?p=list/", "id_vehicle="+id_vehicle+"&brand="+brand)
    .done( function( info ){
        console.log("DATA: " + info);
        info = JSON.parse(info); //AQUI EL ERROR
        renderData(info);
    });
}

function __ajax(url, data){ //Ajax configured
    var ajax = $.ajax({
        "method": "POST",
        "url": url,
        "data": data
    })
    return ajax;
}
```

Recibo el siguiente *`string (var info)`*, pero yo quiero un objeto:

```
[{"id_vehicle":"1","class":"business","brand":"Citroen","model":"C5 2.0hdi","year":"2010","km":"129000"}]
```

El cual al intentar parsear, produce el siguiente error, como informa la consola de chrome:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (controller.php:127)
    at fire (jquery-3.1.1.js:3305)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.1.js:3435)
    at done (jquery-3.1.1.js:9242)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.js:9484)
```

¿Cómo puedo retornar el objeto JSON desde PHP a través de ajax?

Comment: y cual es el problema de recibir ese var info, si lo puedes pasar a un array por lado de javascript o jquery?

Comment: Hay algo raro en la posición 0. Eso está claro. Con qué codificación devuelves el json? UTF-8? Con o sin BOM? Haz un `console.log()` de cada char del json: `for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) { console.log(i, json.charAt(i), json.charCodeAt(i)); }`

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Buena pregunta, espero que puedas obtener respuestas que solucionen tu problema. Saludos.

Comment: Añadiendo a mi comentario, si el `json.charCodeAt(0)` es distinto de 91 (`[`), tienes un código raro al principio que tendrás que depurar y ver de dónde sale.

Comment: Te falta indicarle a la función de Ajax el tipo de datos que esperas usando `dataType`. Algo así: `function __ajax(url, data){ //Ajax configured
    var ajax = $.ajax({
        "method": "POST",
        "url": url,
        "data": data, dataType: "json"
    })`,
Ver: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: si añado el datatype directamente no reacciona nada...

Comment: pues colocalo en una variable y luego se la pasas al dataType por medio del ajax. Ademas de definir el nombre que decepcionara desde el otro lado

Comment: Prueba con dataType `application/json`.

Comment: En el php, antes de la línea `echo json_encode($this->rows);` incluye la línea `header('Content-Type: application/json');`. En el mejor de los casos soluciona tu problema; en el peor, te saldrá un error de que ya se han enviado los _headers_, lo cual podría ser el origen de tu problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado, no es nada del parseo JSON etc.

El problema era simplemente que el documento estaba guardado en codificacion UTF-8 con BOM.

BOM es el caracter que se había insertado en la respuesta y por eso no podía aplicar el JSON.parse();

La solución es guardar en UTF-8 sin BOM.

Answer (score 1):

En base a tu código de retorno `echo json_encode($this->rows);`te comento lo siguiente. Debes recorrer el rows (sl parecer es el resultado directo del la sentencia tu base de datos) de tal forma que armes por cada row un elemento JSON válido. Ejem, es mero ejemplo para que analices y apliques a tu caso.

**En PHP**

```
$json="";

foreach($datas as $this->rows)
{
    $json.=($json==""?"":",")."{nombredelvalor1: '".$datas[Identificador1]."',"; // Identificador1 indice o nombre de columna; esto para texto
    $json.="nombredelvalor2: ".$datas[Identificador2].","; // Identificador2 indice o nombre de columna; esto para un numero o valor booleano (true o false)
    // lo demas necesario
    $json.="nombredelvalorN: ".$datas[IdentificadorN]."}";
 }

$json = "{datos: [".$json."]}";

echo json_encode($json); // finalmente lo retornas
```

**En JavaScript donde recibes**

Si del lado del cliente requieres alguna conversión como

```
var recibido =$.parseJSON(data); //  donde "data" es la respuesta de la ejecución AJAX
```

desde luego el punto anterior lo asignas a una variable y lo formado en PHP lo accesaras con `recibido.datos`.

Comment: Entonces debo crear un string en formato JSON, concatenando tal como has puesto? No es posible convertir un array de php a JSON? Hice algo parecido, creando un objeto y devolviendolo, pero voy a probar lo que dices.

Comment: Yo lo realizo de la forma que te expongo; de esa forma "controlo" los nombre que recibo en el cliente y así cambiar cosas del lado del servidor reduciendo cambios en lo recibido en el cambio; claro salvo el cambio afecte los datos enviados.

Answer (score -2):

tal vez es el parser, intentalo con este:

```
var info = $.parseJSON(data);
```

en vez de:

```
info = JSON.parse(info); //AQUI EL ERROR
```

Comment: Solo para indicarte que [**`windo.JSON.parse` está contenido en `$.parseJSON`**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/28d946384799abcd7608c3beda898a0a11ac88d7/src/core.js#L518-L546)